# MS SQL case inside count

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have zero experience in MS SQL and I'm tearing my hair out trying to convert my MySQL query:

```
select 
    m.Customer,
    count(if(c.AtFault="Me",1,null)) 'MeLate',
    count(if(c.AtFault="You",1,null)) 'YouLate',
    count(*) 'Total'
from m
left join r on m.OrderNumber = r.OrderNumber
left join c on r.ReasonCodeID = c.ID
group by m.Customer
```

This is what I'm trying to run on MS SQL:

```
select 
    m.Customer
    count(CASE WHEN c.AtFault="Me" THEN 1 ELSE null) 'MeLate',
    count(CASE WHEN c.AtFault="You" THEN 1 ELSE null) 'YouLate',
    count(*) 'Total'
from m
left join r on m.OrderNumber = r.OrderNumber
left join c on r.ReasonCodeID = c.ID
group by m.Customer
```

but this throws the uninformative error:

> SQL Error (102): Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: single quotes not double quotes: `='Me'`, missing comma after `m.Customer`

Comment: every case must have an end.  `CASE WHEN c.AtFault='Me' THEN 1 ELSE null END` the else null is unneeded. `CASE WHEN c.AtFault="Me" THEN 1 end`

Comment: @xQbert If I use double quotes in `c.AtFault="Me"` it errors with *"Invalid column name 'Hit'*

Comment: awe the haste of copy / paste yes the " should be '.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three errors:

You are missing the `END` at the end of `CASE WHEN`.

You must use single quote instead double.

Forgot the comma after `m.Customer`

Try this:

```
    select 
        m.Customer,
        count(CASE WHEN c.AtFault='Me' THEN 1 ELSE null END) MeLate,
        count(CASE WHEN c.AtFault='You' THEN 1 ELSE null END) YouLate,
        count(*) Total
    from m
    left join r on m.OrderNumber = r.OrderNumber
    left join c on r.ReasonCodeID = c.ID
    group by m.Customer
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll choose your answer once the timer allows it.

Comment: @David Browne why is it better to leave out the quotes around table aliases?

Comment: Using single quotes for delimited identifiers is not standard.  It's not even documented as working for SQL Server, and it's error prone, as they can be interpreted as literal strings if you place them in the wrong place.  Plus Intellisense identifies them as literal strings.

Comment: SQL server typically uses `[]` where as mySQL uses backtick  to denote objects (tables,fields, views, etc)

Comment: Ok. Thanks @BeetleJuice

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft do you have an opinion about whether to use `count()` as I tried, or `sum()` as Vaibhav's answer does?

Comment: No.  Both count() and sum() are correct, and both are commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

end is missing there and you can try sum instead of count

```
select 
    m.Customer,
    sum(CASE WHEN c.AtFault='Me' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) MeLate,
    sum(CASE WHEN c.AtFault='You' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) YouLate,
    count(*) Total
from m
left join r on m.OrderNumber = r.OrderNumber
left join c on r.ReasonCodeID = c.ID
group by m.Customer
```